# Looking for a strange DOS database GUI that ran on 286+

Tags: ms-dos, identify-this-software

I have recently been getting into older apps from when I was a kid; one of these was this strange DOS shipping(?) database GUI that ran on at least a 286, but looked like Windows 3.1; however when you clicked on the window controls, they just changed color. But the window operations menu from what I recall worked okay.

This is probably a long shot. I would provide screenshots, but alas—I have no further details available, other than this.

I vaguely remember this GUI, and would appreciate any assistance seeing if I can locate it again!

Thanks!

Comment: You might look into dBase III, FoxBase (or later) FoxPro.

Comment: It went out of its way to look like Windows 3.1; It wasn't 100%, but if it helps- I found it once on America Online, I think. Either that or some geocities site. It was shareware, and I used to pine intensely for a "Program Manager for DOS" that I could use on my 286. Yeah, I was a strange kid, but that's how I found that strange database UI, haha.

Comment: I was finally able to locate a screenshot, and though it isn't direct from e.g. dosbox, it demonstrates basically what I remember. And no, this isn't THE application, I suspect the original author was heavily inspired by this [screenshot](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/198707836564406274/699330078840061983/2v9bbxbwfxe31.png?width=854&height=640)

Comment: @RobertButler Ahh. I see what you mean by "went out of its way to look like Windows 3.1". PartitionMagic 3.0 would generate a DOS floppy that did something similar.

Comment: Could it be FoxPro for Windows? https://winworldpc.com/res/img/screenshots/26-60603cdfd51063de1365307029b159d1-Foxpro%202.6a%20for%20Windows%20-%20Splash.png

Comment: No, because we never had Windows 286, and it never ran properly on the 286 I had at the time, so I was bound to DOS. It was like a shipping management application, or some shareware Rolodex type app.

I very clearly remember it because the main difference between it and Windows 3, was that the window buttons simply changed color when 'activated' instead of depressing the way they did under Windows. This was clearly INSPIRED by, but was not Windows itself. Besides I didn't have enough RAM for Windows 3.

Comment: @ssokolow yup. The main difference was that it was 640x480 and used the Wolfenstein 'palette'. The teal window caption. The light grey titlebar.

Comment: Could it be something based on MS-Works 2.0 or 3.0?  Works was an all-in-one GUI which had an in-memory database which could be used for all sorts.  I've seen it used for car clubs and at doctor's surgeries.

Comment: I used Works for DOS 2.0. It has a Text-Mode-like user interface. While it is able to use graphics mode to show italics and boldface in a WYSIWYG manner, the look and feel is much more QBasic/Turbo Vision like than Windows-like. A quick google image search shows that Works 3.0 still is text-like.

Comment: geworks? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6uGpU4RBf4

Comment: Geoworks isn't that unusual, but thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Wild stab: [DataEase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DataEase)? Had both a DOS and Windows version. Still seems to exist, but [here are some older-version Windows screen-shots](http://www.normboynton.com/DFW.htm) I found, in case it jogs a memory. (And [here's a DOS version](https://winworldpc.com/product/dataease/45)).

Comment: It was a graphical DOS app. It tried super hard to look like Windows 3.x, I think it used VGA's 320x240? I think it was designed for the 286?

Answer (score 3):

Could be Borland Reflex? Definitely had a GUI interface.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you think this is the correct answer?

Comment: Reflex has a global menubar; What I remember about that application, it behaved as if it were almost a Windows 3.1 app. It minimized to an icon and maximized to fill the screen. It had this VGA 'teal' color scheme.

Comment: It was worth a try.

Comment: No worries! I'm just puzzled as to what it is; I don't have anything that I can connect to my old harddrive and check for the foreseeable future.